# why is my generic v-for key giving a type error in Vue 3.3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, generics

My app uses Vue 3.3.4 which added support for generics in single file components. My component is a generic list that loops over a set of `items` passed as a prop. Additionally, there is an `itemKey` prop for keying the `v-for` loop.

```js
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T, K extends keyof T">
defineProps<{
  items: Array<T>
  itemKey: K
}>()
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items" :key="item[itemKey]">
      <slot :item="item" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

The `:key="item[itemKey]"` gets highlighted and the following error is shown

```
Type '[{ type: PropType<K>; required: true; }] extends [Prop<infer V, infer D>] ? unknown extends V ? IfAny<V, V, D> : V : { type: PropType<K>; required: true; }' cannot be used to index type 'T'.
```

It should be noted that this is only a type error; the code itself runs.

Why is my `itemKey` being misinterpreted?

---

**TEMPORARY SOLUTION:** Use an inline `//@ts-ignore` in the `:key` prop.

```js
<li
  v-for="(item, i) in items"
  :key="
    //@ts-ignore
    item[itemKey]
  "
>
```

Comment: Seems related to this https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools/issues/3267

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Reflection to your code

[image: original code]

This is **because the type of `itemKey` is generic** in the component definition and is only known at runtime. Therefore, the static type checking of TypeScript cannot determine exactly which key it refers to.

It is necessary to provide a more specific type definition for `items[]`.

[image: type of :key on vue]

In Vue, the `:key` attribute expects `string`, `number`, or `symbol` values. Therefore, if the type of `item[itemKey]` matches one of these types, we use it as the key otherwise, we don't.

#### Solution # 1 - `T extends U ? U : never` - TypeScript 2.8 and above

In this case, we assume that every value in the object `T` can be a valid key. After all, by using `item[itemKey]`, we essentially made this assertion, which is causing the error.

```
Array<{ [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends string | number | symbol ? T[key] : never }>
```

The `items` prop is an array where, based on the keys (`keyof T`) of the `T` type, it selects the types from `T[key]` that are `string`, `number`, or `symbol`. If the types are not one of these, it returns the `never` type.

This ensures that only `string`, `number`, or `symbol` values can be assigned to the `:key` attribute.

```html
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T, K extends keyof T">
defineProps<{
  items: Array<{ [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends string | number | symbol ? T[key] : never }>
  itemKey: K
}>()
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items" :key="item[itemKey]">
      <slot :item="item" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

#### Solution # 2 (declare `item[itemKey]` type)

If the object can contain values of different types, it may not be worth the effort to perform precise type checking. It is advisable to declare `item[itemKey] as a value that meets our expectations for later use. Additionally, you may consider writing runtime JavaScript checks to verify the type of item[itemKey], allowing you to display an error message in the console as an error during development mode.

```html
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T, K extends keyof T">
defineProps<{
  items: Array<T>
  itemKey: K
}>()
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items" :key="(item[itemKey as K] as string | number | symbol)">
      <slot :item="item" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

#### Solution # 3 (convert to string)

If you want to ensure that the `:key` attribute receives a string value, you can simply convert the `item[itemKey]` value to a string. By doing so, TypeScript won't raise any issues because regardless of the actual type of `item[itemKey]`, you have explicitly converted it to a string, which satisfies the requirements of the `:key` attribute.

```html
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T, K extends keyof T">
defineProps<{
  items: Array<T>
  itemKey: K
}>()
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items" :key="String(item[itemKey as K])">
      <slot :item="item" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: I was very close to solution 2 but I like the explicitness of solution 3.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are encountering seems to be a problem with the TypeScript compiler's ability to infer types in Vue's template block. It is not about your `itemKey` being misinterpreted, but more about TypeScript's ability to determine what type it should be in the context of the template.

When TypeScript tries to understand `:key="item[itemKey]"`, it's not able to infer that `itemKey` is indeed a key of item which is likely because the Vue template compiler is not perfectly in sync with TypeScript atm.

Besides using `@ts-ignore` another possible workaround might be to create a method or computed property in your script block that encapsulates the keying operation, and then use this method or property in your template.

```js
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T, K extends keyof T">
const props = defineProps<{
  items: Array<T>
  itemKey: K
}>()

const getItemKey = (item: T) => item[props.itemKey];
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items" :key="getItemKey(item)">
    <slot :item="item" />
  </li>
</ul>
</template>
```

This workaround essentially moves the operation that TypeScript has trouble understanding out of the Vue template and into the script block, where TypeScript's type inference is more reliable.

Comment: Yes, I also thought about this, but in this case, it is not able to determine whether the result of `getItemKey()` is of the appropriate type. And if you also specify the return type, then we are back to the original problem: TypeScript cannot guarantee that the result will indeed be one of the `string | number | symbol` types --> And we're back to the original problem - as you described well - just with an unnecessary extra function.

Comment: Well, that's not ideal. A more type-safe workaround could be to enforce that the itemKey prop must return a value of a type that can be used as a key. This can be achieved by constraining the generic `K` to be a `keyof T` that is also a `string | number | symbol`.